# angular isolate scope's & binding returns getter function instead of value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Inside isolate scope I have the following binding:

```
scope: {
    languages: "&",
}
```

The value is passed like that inside DOM:

```
<directive-name languages="['1', '2']">
```

Then when I try to access `languages` property `scope.languages` returns getter function like the one returned by the `$parse` service only with predefined context. So while I can easily get bound values like that

```
var languages = scope.languages()
```

I still want to make sure that this is indeed expected behavior. So should the `&` binding return predefined context getter function instead of actual values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the whole purpose of using "&".

From the angular docs:

> & or &attr - provides a way to execute an expression in the context of
>   the parent scope. If no attr name is specified then the attribute name
>   is assumed to be the same as the local name. Given  and widget definition of scope: {
>   localFn:'&myAttr' }, then isolate scope property localFn will point to
>   a function wrapper for the count = count + value expression. Often
>   it's desirable to pass data from the isolated scope via an expression
>   to the parent scope, this can be done by passing a map of local
>   variable names and values into the expression wrapper fn. For example,
>   if the expression is increment(amount) then we can specify the amount
>   value by calling the localFn as localFn({amount: 22}).

More info: [AngularJS Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

However if all you want to do is pass that array to your directive all you need to do is evaluate that attribute:

In your directive:

```
scope.languages = scope.$eval(attrs.languages); //This should assign the array ['1', '2'] to your scope property.
```

Comment: or simply use **`'='`** notation :)

Comment: '=' will create watchers, which is redundant in my case

Comment: No, '=' is two way data binding between two scope properties. From the docs again: `= or =attr - set up bi-directional binding between a local scope property and the parent scope property of name defined via the value of the attr attribute.`

Comment: thanks, Wawy, I'll accept your answer. This line is interesting _Often it's desirable to pass data from the isolated scope via an expression to the parent scope, this can be done by passing a map of local variable names and values into the expression wrapper fn_, it means that by adding watcher to the isolate scope property I can update parent's property by calling `localFn({parentProperty: isolatedScopePropertyValue})`. And I wonder if angular does exactly that when the `=` binding is used

Comment: just checked out the source - no second watcher is created. Angular adds just one watcher for parent property and inside that watcher it updates either parent's scope or isolate scope's.

Comment: If you try to assign anything to that scope property in your directive, angular will throw an error. Using '=' for expressions is not the right way of doing things.

Comment: Yeah, this makes sense considering the process I described in my previous comment